# Create Script to catch HTTP Post

Tags: php, http, infusionsoft

I am using Infusionsoft to send http posts. I need a quick script written that grabs the information from the http post and captures the information. I am using iSDK and code is written however there is nothing coming from http, what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
require_once('iSDK/isdk.php');

$appname = "xxxxx";
$apikey ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(true);

$app = new iSDK;

$contactId = intval($_GET['contactId']);


if(($appname == NULL) || ($apikey == NULL)){
    echo "<b>Error</b> - make sure you fill out all the fields";
    exit(0);
}

if(!$app->cfgCon('i', $appname, $apikey))
{
    echo "No connected";
    exit();
}
$result = $app->runAS($contactId, '123');
print_r($result);


echo "Contact Id:". $contactId;
?>
```

Comment: We don't see your post, but post data is not available in `$_GET`.

Comment: Hello, the post is coming from here https://123employee.infusionsoft.com/app/form/431a9b5a69d835ab2d3e8695315acf36

After the form post the HTTP post get called.